# How to pass parameters from Jenkins file to Groovy script file, when both these file are in different jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Jenkins job say Job1 and Job2. Job1 uses Jenkinsfile to execute and Job2 uses Groovy script to execute.

Parameters being used are of type key-value pair, and  these parameters will be passed from Jenkinsfile to Groovy Script so as to run Job2 parallel to Job1.

Please suggest a way to do the above scenario.

Below is my code:

Jenkins(caller)file used in Job1:

```
#!groovy    
library <internal library I am using>


pipeline {              
agent any       
stages {
    stage ('callParallelJob') {     
        steps {
               script { 
                       ------- Some code------                          
                       
                       def gitCommitterEmail = sh (
                       script: 'git --no-pager show -s --format=\'%ae\'',
                       returnStdout: true
                       ).trim()
                       echo "git committer: ${gitCommitterEmail}"
                       appConfig.gitCommitterEmail = gitCommitterEmail
                       
                       def gitBranch = "${env.GIT_BRANCH}".trim()
                       appConfig.gitBranch = gitBranch
                     
                       def jenkinsBuildUrl = "${env.BUILD_URL}".trim()
                       appConfig.jenkinsBuildUrl = jenkinsBuildUrl
                       
                      def ciData = [
                                   'git': [
                                   'git_repo': "${git_repo}",
                                   'git_branch': "${env.BRANCH_NAME}",
                                   'git_committer': "${gitCommitterEmail}",
                                   'git_commit': "${GIT_COMMIT}"
                                          ],
                               'jenkins': [
                               'build_url': "${env.BUILD_URL}",
                               'job_name': "${JOB_NAME}",
                               'timestamp': "${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}"
                                          ]
                                      ]
                            writeYaml file: 'ci.yml', data: ciData 
        
                            echo 'calling another job'              
                       build job: '<job2Namehere>, parameters: [
                       string(name: 'Testparam', value: "123"),
                       ], propagate: true, wait: false      
                       echo 'called another job'  

                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to pass appConfig and ci.yml data to below groovy script

Groovy file used in Job2 :

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Experiment'){
        steps{
              script{
                  sh 'echo ${Testparam}'               
                    

       -------Some code here-------

}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the called job to accept [parameters](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters), then your code should work.

Comment: I tried creating method like def receive(params) in Groovy file and then called it inside script block in groovy file of Job 2. But I am not sure how to send key value pairs present in appConfig and ci.yml in Jenkins file of Job1.

Comment: How do i send params like  ---- build job: '<job2Namehere>, parameters: [                 appConfig ], propagate: true, wait: false

Comment: Did you read the link in my answer? You need to configure the job that receives the parameters (with a parameters block -> see link in answer). Then you can pass the parameters in the build job: <jobName>, parameters: [string(name: ..., value: ...)] step

Comment: I tried but getting error --- java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of interface java.util.List.....
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {job=<jobnamehere>, parameters={appType=javaApp

Comment: here is my job 1 code - build job: '<jobnamehere>', parameters: appConfig, propagate: true, wait: false      
echo 'called another job'